# Search for string in a dataframe entry and copy it python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I have a data frame containing 3 columns

It has three columns say A,B,C

I want to **look for a specific string** say 'apple' **in all rows of column** A and if a particular row contains the string 'apple' I want to **copy it to a new column** D - so that for the same row column D would contain the word 'apple'

I tried using the for loop like:

```
for i in range(16):
    if df.iat[i,1].str.contains('apple').any():
         df.iat[i,2] = 'apple'
```

but it gives me back the error :'str' object has no attribute 'str'

I tried a couple of other approaches but could not figure out how to iterate through specific rows

Comment: Have you tried just following what the error says? `df.iat[i,1]` seems to be returning a string directly, so lose the `.str` after it and jump straight into the `.contains('apple').any():`. Would look like this all together: `if df.iat[i,1].contains('apple').any():`

Comment: I tried using that @ThePoetCoder but it gave the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df
     NAME  VALUE
0   apple      6
1  banana      3
2  cherry      7
3   apple      2
4  banana      5
5  cherry      3
```

**Solution**

Full checks -

```
df.loc[df.eq('apple').any(axis=1), 'NEW'] = 'apple'
```

Alternatively, for substring checks -

```
m = df.select_dtypes(object).apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains('apple')).any(axis=1)
df.loc[m, 'NEW'] = 'apple'
```

```
df

     NAME  VALUE    NEW
0   apple      6  apple
1  banana      3    NaN
2  cherry      7    NaN
3   apple      2  apple
4  banana      5    NaN
5  cherry      3    NaN
```

Comment: The second code is probably i could work with,thanks!
PS: How would I check for multiple strings? Say i want to check if the entry contains 'apple' and 'orange'  and i want the new column to contain both apple and orange if it is present in the previous column.

Comment: @Pankaj It's a non-trivial problem. I would recommend asking a new question as an extension to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @coldspeed's answer, but a bit simpler and works with several different items:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(Name=['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
         Value=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
)

m = df.Name.apply(
    lambda x: x in ['apple', 'orange']
)
df.loc[m, 'NEW'] = df.loc[m, 'Name']

#df
    Name    Value   NEW
0   apple   1   apple
1   banana  2   NaN
2   cherry  3   NaN
3   apple   4   apple
4   banana  5   NaN
5   orange  6   orange
```

This approach also works with substrings:

```
lambda x: 'app' in x or 'oran' in x
```